# Render data in right or left column based on the type using flex

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I would like to create and html view which is populated from the array.

The view has two columns and based on the element type I would like to put element in left or right column for the desktop view.

For the mobile view all elements should be displayed in one column keeping orginal ordering.

Can it achieved with the flex-box?

```
posts.map((i, index) => {

   // render items 
   // i.type === 'male' -> should be in left column
   // i.type === 'female' -> should be in right column
}
 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can this;

```
<div className="container">
  {posts.map((post, index) => (
    <div key={index} className={`post ${post.type}`}>
      {post.content}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

---

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.post.male {
  order: -1;
}

.post.female {
  order: 1;
}
```

Comment: Something is not right. It first renders 'male' posts in both left and right columns and then 'female' posts in both right and left columns

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain this issue, what do you need exactly @macfly

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1vc0Ly49/5/ as you can see male elements are in both columns - right and left. I want them to be only in left and female in right column

Comment: can you check this? https://jsfiddle.net/muammertopcu/bt2fa70o/ @macfly

Comment: we are almost there. the only thing missing is that posts should be listed in one column for the mobile view and the order of elements should kept as we have it in the array. in my scenerio they should be ordered by creation date

Comment: you can try it with non-filtered data for mobile views. I don't think the structure you want can be solved with other things. @macfly